# Algorithm to swap independent and dependent variables of function samples

Tags: algorithm, math

Suppose you have several functions y1 = f1(x), y2 = f2(x), etc. and you want to plot their graphs together on one plot.
Imagine now that for some reason it is easier to obtain the set of x for a given y; as in, there exists an oracle which given a y, will return all the x1, x2, etc. in increasing order for which y = f1(x1), y = f2(x2), etc.. In essence, it computes the inverse functions given a y. Suppose you uniformly sample in y, so you have a list of lists of x's. If you plot this data treating all the first x in each sublist as a function of y, and all the second x's in each sublist as a different function of y, etc., you obtain a plot like below.

[image: plot before]

In the above plot, the horizontal axis is y, and the vertical axis is x.
Note that the navy blue "curve" is the set of smallest x as a function of y (the set of points you would see looking up from underneath the plot), while the magenta curve is the set of second smallest x, etc. Obviously, the far left navy blue and magenta curves belong to a single function and should be connected. As you move towards the right, there are ambiguities and cross-overs. In those cases, it doesn't matter how the curves of the functions are connected, as long as it "looks" reasonable (there is a proper way, but I'll settle for this for now).

Now, the algorithm output should be samples of y as a function of x for each function, which when you plot it would look like:

[image: plot after]

(Apologies for the poor Paint edit job :)

I was thinking I proceed going one column at a time in the first pic and trying to match adjacent values based on slopes and how close they are to each other, but I'm not sure if there is a better way. Also, if this is a solved or documented problem, then I have no idea what to Google for, so any pointers would be helpful.

**Aside**

The actual application is in the computation of band structures of crystals, for anyone who is curious. The functions are the bands of the crystal, with the horizontal axis of the first plot being frequency, and the vertical axis is the k-vector. It turns out solving an eigenvalue problem for each frequency to get the eigenvalues (the k's) is easier in this case. It is fairly common to need to "prettify" and connect the resulting band structure plots, and I was wondering if there is an algorithmic way of doing it instead of having to do it by hand.

Comment: This reminds me of http://www.xkcd.com/664/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in the end I came up with a reasonable greedy algorithm. I first proceed to decompose the existing data into pieces which are one-to-one (they don't bend back in either domain). Then these pieces are grown from one end by considering all possible candidate pieces that can be joined to it, and an optimal one is chosen based on an error metric. The error metric considers nearness of the segment endpoints, the nearness of the endpoint slopes, as well as nearness of points to segment extrapolation. I will post the rather length code below in case people are searching for this kind of thing. The large comment blocks explain what is going on. The terminology used in the code are specific to the application, which I explained in the aside above.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <float.h>

const double max_relative_k_error_for_local_min_duplication = 0.05;
const double max_k_to_be_considered_separate_band = 0.1; // relative to entire k extent

typedef std::pair<double,double> band_point; // first is k, second is omega
struct band_point_sorter{
    bool operator()(const band_point &a, const band_point &b){
        return a.first < b.first;
    }
};
struct band_piece{ // a one-to-one piece
    size_t n;
    std::vector<band_point> points;
    band_piece(size_t N, const std::vector<band_point> &pts):n(N),points(pts){}
    template <class Iter>
    band_piece(size_t N, Iter first, Iter last):n(N),points(first, last){
        std::sort(points.begin(), points.end(), band_point_sorter());
    }
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const band_piece &p){
    os << "(" << p.points.front().second << "," << p.points.front().first << ")-(" << p.points.back().second << "," << p.points.back().first << ")";
    return os;
}
typedef std::vector<band_point> band_cluster; // a continuous set of one-to-one pieces
typedef std::vector<size_t> band; // index of one-to-one pieces
struct k_extent{
    double kmin, kmax;
    k_extent(const k_extent &ext):kmin(ext.kmin),kmax(ext.kmax){}
    k_extent(double KMin, double KMax):kmin(KMin),kmax(KMax){
        if(kmin > kmax){ std::swap(kmin,kmax); }
    }
    k_extent(const std::vector<band_point> &pts):kmin(pts.front().first),kmax(pts.back().first){
        if(kmin > kmax){ std::swap(kmin,kmax); }
    }
    void Union(const k_extent &b){
        if(b.kmin < kmin){ kmin = b.kmin; }
        if(b.kmax > kmax){ kmax = b.kmax; }
    }
};

bool KExtentsOverlap(const k_extent &a, const k_extent &b){
    return (a.kmin <= b.kmin && b.kmin <= a.kmax)
        || (a.kmin <= b.kmax && b.kmax <= a.kmax)
        || (b.kmin <= a.kmin && a.kmin <= b.kmax)
        || (b.kmin <= a.kmax && a.kmax <= b.kmax);
}

struct PieceJoiningErrorMetric{
    double k_normalization;
    double domega;
    PieceJoiningErrorMetric(const double &min_slope, const double &omega_step):k_normalization(1/min_slope),domega(omega_step){}
    double operator()(const std::vector<band_point> &p0, const std::vector<band_point> &p1){
        // We have a number of criteria that we want:
        //  0 The nearest endpoints of the pieces should be close in k.
        //  1 The slopes at the near end points should be close.
        //  2 The linear extension from the near ends of the pieces should almost match.
        // Criterion 2 is the most difficult to quantify:
        //  If we shoot a ray out from the endpoint of one segment, the point on the
        //  ray nearest the other piece's endpoint should not be the ray origin (the
        //  nearest point on the ray to the other endpoint should be at a positive
        //  ray coordinate). We do this for both segment endpoints, and take the larger
        //  of the two minimum distances.
        double dk0 = 0, dk1 = 0, dw0 = 0, dw1 = 0, slope0, slope1;
        double slope0_2; // slopes of next neighboring points
        double slope1_2;
        double k0, k1, k_diff, w0, w1;
        if(p1.front().first > p0.back().first){ // p1 entirely after p0
            k0 = p0.back().first; w0 = p0.back().second;
            if(p0.size() > 1){
                dk0 = p0.back().first - p0[p0.size()-2].first;
                dw0 = p0.back().second - p0[p0.size()-2].second;
                slope0 = dw0/dk0;
                if(p1.size() < 2){
                    slope1 = slope0;
                }
                if(p0.size() > 4){ // give extra space since for too short segments, this is meaningless
                    slope0_2 = (p0[p0.size()-2].second - p0[p0.size()-3].second)/(p0[p0.size()-2].first - p0[p0.size()-3].first);
                }
            }
            k1 = p1.front().first; w1 = p1.front().second;
            if(p1.size() > 1){
                dk1 = p1.front().first - p1[1].first;
                dw1 = p1.front().second - p1[1].second;
                slope1 = dw1/dk1;
                if(p0.size() < 2){
                    slope0 = slope1;
                }
                if(p1.size() > 4){ // give extra space since for too short segments, this is meaningless
                    slope1_2 = (p1[1].second - p1[2].second)/(p1[1].first - p1[2].first);
                }
            }
            k_diff = k1 - k0;
        }else if(p0.front().first > p1.back().first){ // p0 entirely after p1
            k0 = p0.front().first; w0 = p0.front().second;
            if(p0.size() > 1){
                dk0 = p0.front().first - p0[1].first;
                dw0 = p0.front().second - p0[1].second;
                slope0 = dw0/dk0;
                if(p1.size() < 2){
                    slope1 = slope0;
                }
                if(p0.size() > 4){ // give extra space since for too short segments, this is meaningless
                    slope0_2 = (p0[1].second - p0[2].second)/(p0[1].first - p0[2].first);
                }
            }
            k1 = p1.back().first; w1 = p1.back().second;
            if(p1.size() > 1){
                dk1 = p1.back().first - p1[p1.size()-2].first;
                dw1 = p1.back().second - p1[p1.size()-2].second;
                slope1 = dw1/dk1;
                if(p0.size() < 2){
                    slope0 = slope1;
                }
                if(p1.size() > 4){ // give extra space since for too short segments, this is meaningless
                    slope1_2 = (p1[p1.size()-2].second - p1[p1.size()-3].second)/(p1[p1.size()-2].first - p1[p1.size()-3].first);
                }
            }
            k_diff = k0 - k1;
        }else{
            return DBL_MAX;
        }
        k0 *= k_normalization;
        k1 *= k_normalization;
        dk0 *= k_normalization;
        dk1 *= k_normalization;
        k_diff *= k_normalization;
        if(p0.size() < 2 && p1.size() < 2){
            return k_diff*k_diff;
        }
        slope0 /= k_normalization;
        slope1 /= k_normalization;

        // max abs value for any slope here is 1

        //// Perform the ray shooting
        // Suppose we start at k0,w0, the ray is
        //   (k0,w0) + t*(dk0,dw0)
        // Distance^2 to k1 is
        //   (k0-k1+t*dk0)^2 + (w0-w1+t*dw0)^2
        // Minimize by taking derivative w.r.t. t:
        //   t = [ (k1-k0)*dk0 + (w1-w0)*dw0 ] / (dk0*dk0 + dw0*dw0);
        double t, x;

        t = ((k1-k0)*dk0 + (w1-w0)*dw0) * (dk0*dk0 + dw0*dw0); if(t < 0){ return DBL_MAX; }
        double dist2_01 = 0;
        x = k0-k1+t*dk0;
        dist2_01 += x*x;
        x = w0-w1+t*dw0;
        dist2_01 += x*x;

        t = ((k0-k1)*dk1 + (w0-w1)*dw1) * (dk1*dk1 + dw1*dw1); if(t < 0){ return DBL_MAX; }
        double dist2_10 = 0;
        x = k1-k0+t*dk1;
        dist2_10 += x*x;
        x = w1-w0+t*dw1;
        dist2_10 += x*x;

        //double k_scale = (dk1 > dk0) ? dk1 : dk0;
        //double k_ext0 = p0.back().first - p0.front().first;
        //double k_ext1 = p1.back().first - p1.front().first;
        //double k_scale = (k_ext0 < k_ext1) ? k_ext0 : k_ext1;

        double w_diff = fabs(w1-w0);

        // We take the larger of the ray shooting distances
        double dist2 = (dist2_01 > dist2_10) ? dist2_01 : dist2_10;

        // We take the difference of slopes here and multiply by k_diff to get something in omega range
        // Further, we take the next neighboring slopes in case the slopes are corrupted due to being near a degeneracy.
        double dslope = fabs(slope0-slope1) * k_diff;
        if(p0.size() > 4 && p1.size() > 4){
            double dslope_2 = fabs(slope0_2-slope1_2) * k_diff;
            if(dslope_2 < dslope){ dslope = dslope_2; }
        }

        // scale oemga difference by slope so that for shallow slopes, we really want to get
        // a good frequency match, also scales from omega range to k range
        double max_slope = (std::abs(slope0) > std::abs(slope1)) ? slope0 : slope1;
        w_diff /= max_slope;

//      std::cerr << "        k_diff = " << k_diff << ", w_diff = " << w_diff << ", slope0 = " << slope0 << ", slope1 = " << slope1 << ", dist2 = " << dist2 << std::endl;
        return k_diff*k_diff + w_diff*w_diff + dslope*dslope + dist2;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    std::vector<double> freqs;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > raw_bands;

    double max_k_extent = -DBL_MAX;
    double min_k_extent = DBL_MAX;
    double max_freq_extent = -DBL_MAX;
    double min_freq_extent = DBL_MAX;
    size_t max_num_k_per_omega = 0;
    double min_slope = DBL_MAX; // dk/dw

    std::ifstream in(argv[1]);
    if(!in.is_open()){
        std::cerr << "Could not open file: " << argv[1] << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::string line;
    while(getline(in, line)){
        std::istringstream line_in(line);
        double val;
        line_in >> val;
        freqs.push_back(val);
        if(val < min_freq_extent){ min_freq_extent = val; }
        if(val > max_freq_extent){ max_freq_extent = val; }

        raw_bands.push_back(std::vector<double>());
        while(line_in){
            double val;
            if(line_in >> val){
                raw_bands.back().push_back(val);
                if(val < min_k_extent){ min_k_extent = val; }
                if(val > max_k_extent){ max_k_extent = val; }
            }
        }
        if(raw_bands.back().size() > max_num_k_per_omega){ max_num_k_per_omega = raw_bands.back().size(); }
    }

    //// Split into one-to-one pieces
    // A one-to-one piece is a connected subset of an omega-k band which is
    // one-to-one with respect to omega and k.
    //  For a given n, the set of n-th smallest k values as a function of a
    // omega is disjoint on the omega domain. We call a single connected part
    // of the omega domain for a single set of n-th smallest k values an
    // n-shadow, and the connected subset of the omega-k band an n-cluster.
    // n-clusters are separated from one another by the bandgaps, so they are
    // easy to distinguish.
    //  Each n-cluster is itself a conjunction of several one-to-one pieces.
    // Boundaries between one-to-one pieces are defined by local minima or
    // maxima on the omega domain, or by large jump discontinuities (jumps
    // in k). We need to set a threshold beyond which jumps are considered
    // one-to-one piece boundaries.
    //
    // For each band we first construct the n-clusters, then divide them into
    // one-to-one pieces.

    std::vector<band_piece> all_pieces;
    for(size_t n = 0; n < max_num_k_per_omega; ++n){
        // n is the n-th smallest k we are considering

        // First collect all the clusters
        std::vector<band_cluster> clusters;
        size_t w = 0;
        while(raw_bands[w].size() <= n){ ++w; }
        for(; w < raw_bands.size(); ++w){
            if(raw_bands[w].size() > n){
                // If we are in a gap, there is nothing to do, otherwise...
                if(0 == w || raw_bands[w-1].size() <= n){
                    // Encountering more k's, time to start a new cluster
                    clusters.push_back(band_cluster());
                    clusters.back().push_back(band_point(raw_bands[w][n], freqs[w]));
                }else if(raw_bands[w-1].size() > n){
                    // We are within a cluster
                    clusters.back().push_back(band_point(raw_bands[w][n], freqs[w]));
                }
            }
        }

        // Now break each cluster into pieces
        for(size_t c = 0; c < clusters.size(); ++c){
            const band_cluster &cur_cluster = clusters[c];
            band_cluster::const_iterator last_cut_loc = cur_cluster.begin();
            // We skip first and last of each cluster since we can not cut adjacent to them
            for(size_t w = 1; w < cur_cluster.size()-1; ++w){
                double slope1 = fabs((cur_cluster[w].first - cur_cluster[w-1].first)/(cur_cluster[w].second-cur_cluster[w-1].second));
                if(slope1 < min_slope){ min_slope = slope1; }
                if(cur_cluster[w].first < cur_cluster[w-1].first && cur_cluster[w].first < cur_cluster[w+1].first){
                    // Check for local minimum
                    if(w > 1){
                        if(w >= cur_cluster.size()-2){
                            // can only get slope on the left, award to the left
                            if(last_cut_loc == cur_cluster.begin()+w+1){ continue; }
                            all_pieces.push_back(band_piece(n, last_cut_loc, cur_cluster.begin()+w+1)); // note the +1, duplicates the extremum point
                            last_cut_loc = cur_cluster.begin()+w+2; ++w;
                        }else{
                            // Can get slope on both sides
                            double  left_k_extrapolation = (cur_cluster[w-1].first-cur_cluster[w-2].first) * (cur_cluster[w].second-cur_cluster[w-2].second)/(cur_cluster[w-1].second-cur_cluster[w-2].second) + cur_cluster[w-2].first;
                            double right_k_extrapolation = (cur_cluster[w+1].first-cur_cluster[w+2].first) * (cur_cluster[w].second-cur_cluster[w+2].second)/(cur_cluster[w+1].second-cur_cluster[w+2].second) + cur_cluster[w+2].first;
                            // errors (units of k)
                            double  left_l1_err = fabs( left_k_extrapolation-cur_cluster[w].first);
                            double right_l1_err = fabs(right_k_extrapolation-cur_cluster[w].first);

                            // Determine if the minimum should be copied
                            bool dup_min = false;

                            { // might prefer to use a ray shooting criterion
                                double kext = fabs(all_pieces.back().points.front().first - all_pieces.back().points.back().first);
                                if(left_l1_err/kext < max_relative_k_error_for_local_min_duplication && right_l1_err/kext < max_relative_k_error_for_local_min_duplication){
                                    dup_min = true;
                                }
                            }
                            if(left_l1_err < right_l1_err){
                                if(last_cut_loc == cur_cluster.begin()+w+1){ continue; }
                                all_pieces.push_back(band_piece(n, last_cut_loc, cur_cluster.begin()+w+1));
                                if(dup_min){
                                    last_cut_loc = cur_cluster.begin()+w;
                                }else{
                                    last_cut_loc = cur_cluster.begin()+w+1; ++w;
                                }
                            }else{
                                if(dup_min){
                                    if(last_cut_loc == cur_cluster.begin()+w+1){ continue; }
                                    all_pieces.push_back(band_piece(n, last_cut_loc, cur_cluster.begin()+w+1));
                                }else{
                                    if(last_cut_loc == cur_cluster.begin()+w){ continue; }
                                    all_pieces.push_back(band_piece(n, last_cut_loc, cur_cluster.begin()+w));
                                }
                                last_cut_loc = cur_cluster.begin()+w;
                            }
                        }
                    }else if(w < cur_cluster.size()-2){ // && w <= 1
                        // can only get slope on the right, award to the right
                        if(last_cut_loc == cur_cluster.begin()+w){ continue; }
                        all_pieces.push_back(band_piece(n, last_cut_loc, cur_cluster.begin()+w));
                        last_cut_loc = cur_cluster.begin()+w;
                    }else{
                        // by default give to the right
                        if(last_cut_loc == cur_cluster.begin()+w){ continue; }
                        all_pieces.push_back(band_piece(n, last_cut_loc, cur_cluster.begin()+w));
                        last_cut_loc = cur_cluster.begin()+w;
                    }

                    // Determine whether to duplicate the minimum point
                }else if(cur_cluster[w].first > cur_cluster[w-1].first && cur_cluster[w].first > cur_cluster[w+1].first){
                    // Check for local maximum
                    // Which side gets the maximum point is deterined by slope matching
                    if(w > 1){
                        if(w >= cur_cluster.size()-2){
                            // can only get slope on the left, award to the left
                            if(last_cut_loc == cur_cluster.begin()+w+1){ continue; }
                            all_pieces.push_back(band_piece(n, last_cut_loc, cur_cluster.begin()+w+1));
                            last_cut_loc = cur_cluster.begin()+w+1; ++w;
                        }else{
                            // Can get slope on both sides
                            double  left_k_extrapolation = (cur_cluster[w-1].first-cur_cluster[w-2].first) * (cur_cluster[w].second-cur_cluster[w-2].second)/(cur_cluster[w-1].second-cur_cluster[w-2].second) + cur_cluster[w-2].first;
                            double right_k_extrapolation = (cur_cluster[w+1].first-cur_cluster[w+2].first) * (cur_cluster[w].second-cur_cluster[w+2].second)/(cur_cluster[w+1].second-cur_cluster[w+2].second) + cur_cluster[w+2].first;
                            double  left_l1_err = fabs( left_k_extrapolation-cur_cluster[w].first);
                            double right_l1_err = fabs(right_k_extrapolation-cur_cluster[w].first);
                            if(left_l1_err < right_l1_err){
                                if(last_cut_loc == cur_cluster.begin()+w+1){ continue; }
                                all_pieces.push_back(band_piece(n, last_cut_loc, cur_cluster.begin()+w+1));
                                last_cut_loc = cur_cluster.begin()+w+1; ++w;
                            }else{
                                if(last_cut_loc == cur_cluster.begin()+w){ continue; }
                                all_pieces.push_back(band_piece(n, last_cut_loc, cur_cluster.begin()+w));
                                last_cut_loc = cur_cluster.begin()+w;
                            }
                        }
                    }else if(w < cur_cluster.size()-2){ // && w <= 1
                        // can only get slope on the right, award to the right
                        if(last_cut_loc == cur_cluster.begin()+w){ continue; }
                        all_pieces.push_back(band_piece(n, last_cut_loc, cur_cluster.begin()+w)); // note the +1, duplicates the extremum point
                        last_cut_loc = cur_cluster.begin()+w;
                    }else{
                        // by default give to the right
                        if(last_cut_loc == cur_cluster.begin()+w){ continue; }
                        all_pieces.push_back(band_piece(n, last_cut_loc, cur_cluster.begin()+w)); // note the +1, duplicates the extremum point
                        last_cut_loc = cur_cluster.begin()+w;
                    }
                }else if(w > 1){
                    // Check for jump discontinuity
                    double diff0 = cur_cluster[w-1].first-cur_cluster[w-2].first;
                    double diff1 = cur_cluster[w  ].first-cur_cluster[w-1].first;
                    double diff2 = cur_cluster[w+1].first-cur_cluster[w  ].first;
                    if((diff0 > 0 && diff1 > 0 && diff2 > 0) || (diff0 < 0 && diff1 < 0 && diff2 < 0)){
                        diff0 = fabs(diff0);
                        diff1 = fabs(diff1);
                        diff2 = fabs(diff2);
                        if(diff1 > diff2 && diff1 > diff0){
                            const double &larger_neighboring_diff = (diff0 > diff2) ? diff0 : diff2;
                            if(diff1 > 5.0 * larger_neighboring_diff){
                                if(last_cut_loc == cur_cluster.begin()+w){ continue; }
                                all_pieces.push_back(band_piece(n, last_cut_loc, cur_cluster.begin()+w));
                                last_cut_loc = cur_cluster.begin()+w;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(last_cut_loc == cur_cluster.end()){ continue; }
            all_pieces.push_back(band_piece(n, last_cut_loc, cur_cluster.end()));
        }
    }

    /*
    // Output all pieces to check them
    for(size_t i = 0; i < all_pieces.size(); ++i){
        std::cout << "Piece " << i << ":" << std::endl;
        for(size_t j = 0; j < all_pieces[i].points.size(); ++j){
            std::cout << " " << all_pieces[i].points[j].first << "\t" << all_pieces[i].points[j].second << std::endl;
        }
    }
    */
    /*
    size_t max_piece_size = 0;
    size_t max_piece_ind = 0;
    for(size_t b = 0; b < all_pieces.size(); ++b){
        if(all_pieces[b].points.size() > max_piece_size){ max_piece_size = all_pieces[b].points.size(); }
    }
    std::cout << "# " << all_pieces.size() << " pieces" << std::endl;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < max_piece_size; ++i){
        for(size_t b = 0; b < all_pieces.size(); ++b){
            if(all_pieces[b].points.size() <= i){
                std::cout << "\t" << all_pieces[b].points.back().first << "\t" << all_pieces[b].points.back().second;
            }else{
                std::cout << "\t" << all_pieces[b].points[i].first << "\t" << all_pieces[b].points[i].second;
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
    */

    //// One-to-one piece connection
    // The set of one-to-one pieces must now be joined into bands. Note that
    // a band must stretch from min_k_extent to max_k_extent (thereabouts) and
    // so will rarely consist of a single one-to-one piece (unless it is a
    // monotonically varying band).
    //  Invariants:
    //   0 The number of pieces from all 0-clusters determines the number of
    //     bands present.
    //   1 A piece from an n-cluster cannot be joined to another piece from
    //     an n-cluster (cannot join same n's).
    //   2 All pieces from a single n-cluster must lie in different bands.
    //   3 A piece cannot be joined to another piece whose k-extents overlap.
    //   4 A junction can only be incident on an even number of pieces. This
    //     is usually 2 unless there is a degeneracy or cross over.
    //   5 A piece from an n-cluster can only be joined to a piece from an
    //     n+k-cluster, where k is -M to M, where M is the multiplicity of
    //     the junction if there is a degeneracy, otherwise it is 1. k not 0.
    //
    // We shall proceed as follows. We will try to grow the bands from min k
    // to max k, starting with seed pieces from the 0-clusters. At the large k
    // tip of every partial band we will consider all possible pieces to join
    // to it. This can be done efficiently by maintaining the set of k-extents
    // for each piece. The best possible piece to use will be the minimizer of
    // an error metric.
    //  The error metric considers both nearness of piece endpoints as well as
    // slope continuity. In all cases, we work in normalized space in which
    // the extent in group velocity is unity (k and omega are scaled similarly)

    const size_t npieces = all_pieces.size();
    std::vector<k_extent> piece_k_extents;
    std::vector<band> partial_bands;
    std::vector<k_extent> partial_band_k_extents;
    std::set<size_t> remaining_pieces;

    // Initialize our structures
    piece_k_extents.reserve(npieces);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < all_pieces.size(); ++i){
        piece_k_extents.push_back(k_extent(all_pieces[i].points));
        if(0 == all_pieces[i].n){ // use Invariants 0 and 2
            if(all_pieces[i].points.front().first-min_k_extent < max_k_to_be_considered_separate_band * (max_k_extent-min_k_extent)){
                partial_bands.push_back(band()); partial_bands.back().push_back(i);
                partial_band_k_extents.push_back(piece_k_extents.back());
            }else{
                remaining_pieces.insert(i);
            }
        }else{
            remaining_pieces.insert(i);
        }
    }

    // Perform the growing
    PieceJoiningErrorMetric error_metric(min_slope, freqs[1]-freqs[0]);
    bool made_progress = true;
    size_t npass = 0;
    while(!remaining_pieces.empty() && made_progress){
//      std::cerr << "Pass " << npass << std::endl;
        made_progress = false;
        // Try to grow each band one piece at a time
        for(size_t b = 0; b < partial_bands.size(); ++b){
            band &cur_band = partial_bands[b];
            std::set<size_t> candidate_pieces;
            for(std::set<size_t>::const_iterator i = remaining_pieces.begin(); i != remaining_pieces.end(); ++i){
                if(*i != all_pieces[cur_band.back()].n){ // use Invariant 1
                    if(!KExtentsOverlap(piece_k_extents[*i], partial_band_k_extents[b])){ // use Invariant 3
                        candidate_pieces.insert(*i);
                    }
                }
            }

            if(candidate_pieces.empty()){ continue; }


            // Find best piece to use
            double error = DBL_MAX;
            size_t best_piece_so_far = (size_t)-1;
//          std::cerr << "  Considering joining " << cur_band.back() << " " << all_pieces[cur_band.back()] << " with:" << std::endl;
            for(std::set<size_t>::const_iterator i = candidate_pieces.begin(); i != candidate_pieces.end(); ++i){
//              std::cerr << "    " << *i << " " << all_pieces[*i] << std::endl;
                double new_error = error_metric(all_pieces[cur_band.back()].points, all_pieces[*i].points);
                if(new_error < error){
                    error = new_error;
                    best_piece_so_far = *i;
                }
            }
            if((size_t)-1 == best_piece_so_far){
//              std::cerr << "  Could not find a good candidate" << std::endl;
                continue;
            }
//          std::cerr << "  Joining with " << best_piece_so_far << " " << all_pieces[best_piece_so_far] << std::endl;
            // Join the piece
            partial_band_k_extents[b].Union(piece_k_extents[best_piece_so_far]);
            cur_band.push_back(best_piece_so_far);
            remaining_pieces.erase(remaining_pieces.find(best_piece_so_far));
            made_progress = true;
        }
        ++npass;
    }
/*
    // Output all bands
    for(size_t b = 0; b < partial_bands.size(); ++b){
        std::cout << "Band " << b << ":" << std::endl;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < partial_bands[b].size(); ++i){
            const band_piece &cur_piece = all_pieces[partial_bands[b][i]];
            for(size_t j = 0; j < cur_piece.points.size(); ++j){
                std::cout << " " << cur_piece.points[j].first << "\t" << cur_piece.points[j].second << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
*/
    size_t max_band_size = 0;
    std::vector<std::vector<band_point> > final_bands(partial_bands.size());
    for(size_t b = 0; b < partial_bands.size(); ++b){
        for(size_t i = 0; i < partial_bands[b].size(); ++i){
            final_bands[b].insert(final_bands[b].end(), all_pieces[partial_bands[b][i]].points.begin(), all_pieces[partial_bands[b][i]].points.end());
        }
        if(final_bands[b].size() > max_band_size){ max_band_size = final_bands[b].size(); }
    }
    for(size_t i = 0; i < max_band_size; ++i){
        for(size_t b = 0; b < final_bands.size(); ++b){
            if(final_bands[b].size() <= i){
                std::cout << "\t" << final_bands[b].back().first << "\t" << final_bands[b].back().second;
            }else{
                std::cout << "\t" << final_bands[b][i].first << "\t" << final_bands[b][i].second;
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Unused pieces:" << std::endl;
    for(std::set<size_t>::const_iterator i = remaining_pieces.begin(); i != remaining_pieces.end(); ++i){
        std::cout << "Piece " << *i << std::endl;
        const band_piece &cur_piece = all_pieces[*i];
        for(size_t j = 0; j < cur_piece.points.size(); ++j){
            std::cout << " " << cur_piece.points[j].first << "\t" << cur_piece.points[j].second << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a "connect the dots" problem, with some constraints:

1. It looks as if each curve appears over the whole range of x (pretty much).

   The curves you are looking for are functions (of x) and therefore can't "double back".

   It looks as if these curves have limited slope and curvature (first and second derivatives, f' and f'').

You can pick a point at the minimum x and work your way along that curve by looking for the most likely next point: look for the nearest point, and usually there'll be one clear winner. If there are two contenders,  pick the one that best obeys the slope and curvature constraints. As you construct the curve, remove those points from the pool, and when that curve is done start on the next one back at xmin. You'll probably have to put in a couple of rules of thumb to deal with stray points and glitches, but I think that'll do it.

Answer (score -1):

All you need is to store all the points (x,y) in an array like data structure.  Then sort the list of points by their x value (you may have to write a custom compare function) and out pops your beautiful function.  I think excel can even do this.

Comment: I don't see how sorting the points by x will associate them into curves.